# recursive variant container compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, variant

I'd like a variant contain copies of objects of its type. Somehow it is not working:

```
struct value
{
};

class json;

using json = ::boost::variant<
  ::std::vector<::std::unique_ptr<json> >,
  ::std::unordered_map<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<json> >,
  value
>;

json.hpp:116:2: error: conflicting declaration 'using json = '
 >;
  ^
json.hpp:110:7: error: 'class json' has a previous declaration as 'class json'
 class json;
```

I know of 2 workarounds already: `::std::unique_ptr<void>`, with a custom deleter, as well as the possibility of using `::boost::any` instead of the variant, but are these the only ways? The problem with `::boost::any` is that I need to enable `RTTI` for it to work.

Comment: Well, the problem is the name conflict. You don't you alias the boost variant as `json_variant` or something?

Comment: You want a `recursive_variant` (… or whatever it's called). Boost has a specific interface for this. For what it's worth, `class json;` means you are going to have a class named `json`, which the typedef-name declared by `using =` is not.

Comment: @user1095108 Not really an SO-worthy answer, but you should read http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive

Comment: @Potatoswatter I try to overcome the "incomplete type" problem by using  `::std::unique_ptr`. If there exists a way to declare `json` some other way, that will compile, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @user1095108 I'm not personally a Boost user, but see the linked tutorial. `unique_ptr` is a valid, but inefficient workaround. It's better to use the library as it was intended.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I am not keen on using boost either, hence I was hoping to see a non-boost workaround.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Look at this, the `recursive_variant_wrapper` uses a `shared_ptr` internally. I think the `unique_ptr` is better! Was a bit worried there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932208/boostvariant-recursive-trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
struct json : ::boost::variant<
  ::std::vector<::std::unique_ptr<json> >,
  ::std::unordered_map<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<json> >,
  value
>
{
  using variant::variant;

  template <typename U>
  json& operator=(U&& u)
  {
    variant::operator=(::std::forward<U>(u));

    return *this;
  }
};
```

That would be the solution, except it doesn't work for me with g++ (constructing json out of vector fails because of ambiguous constructor call). Construction from *a const reference* to such a vector works, but not not from a non-const reference. I have no idea why. In addition, `unique_ptr` doesn't work with `boost::variant` for me because it's uncopyable (`shared_ptr` does work).

Comment: The problem with your solution is that constructors are not inherited, perhaps with inherited constructors...

Comment: Oops, yes, one needs to inherit constructors. Fixing.

Comment: Could be a bug of the standard itself. Does it demand the copy constructor of a vector to be `SFINAE`d away, if `value_type` is non-copyable? This is causing the problems (which can be remedied by using a `shared_ptr`).